# Grails : Plugin [controllers:3.3.9] could not reload changes to file

Tags: grails

I am running into a ghost of a problem. It happens sporadically. It has to do with controllers reloading after changes. Most times I am able to work around by reverting changes and starting fresh, however I am currently stuck. Below is the stacktrace.

```
File /Users/mcroteau/Development/projects/greenfield/grails-app/controllers/greenfield/DataController.groovy changed, recompiling...
2019-01-07 20:05:32.374 ERROR --- [       Thread-7] o.g.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager  : Plugin [controllers:3.3.9] could not reload changes to file [/Users/mcroteau/Development/projects/greenfield/grails-app/controllers/greenfield/DataController.groovy]: No signature of method: grails.core.DefaultGrailsApplication.isArtefactOfType() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource) values: [TagLib, file [/Users/mcroteau/Development/projects/greenfield/grails-app/controllers/greenfield/DataController.groovy]]
Possible solutions: isArtefactOfType(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class), isArtefactOfType(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.core.DefaultGrailsApplication.isArtefactOfType() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource) values: [TagLib, file [/Users/mcroteau/Development/projects/greenfield/grails-app/controllers/greenfield/DataController.groovy]]
Possible solutions: isArtefactOfType(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class), isArtefactOfType(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:71)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:53)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
        at org.grails.plugins.web.GroovyPagesGrailsPlugin.onChange(GroovyPagesGrailsPlugin.groovy:305)
        at org.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.notifyOfEvent(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:750)
        at grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.informObservers(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:210)
        at org.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.notifyOfEvent(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:774)
        at org.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.informOfClassChange(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:548)
        at org.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.informOfFileChange(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:488)
        at grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManager$informOfFileChange$2.call(Unknown Source)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$_enableDevelopmentModeWatch_closure1.doCall(GrailsApp.groovy:250)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$_enableDevelopmentModeWatch_closure1.doCall(GrailsApp.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:418)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:499)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here is one project it is currently happening in: https://github.com/opengreenfield/greenfield - branch internationalization, DataController. Im ok with deleting things.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your package definition and folder structure do not match. I am guessing grails gets confused by this. Try lining them up.